# Use AutoHotKey to auto answer calls from Google Voice?

Tags: autohotkey, google-voice

I want Google Voice phone calls to be answered automatically on my PC.

Is there a way AutoHotKey can test for an incoming call or test to see if the answer button appears in my browser and then click it to answer the call?  The answer button only appears when there is an incoming call.  I am wanting this to answer multiple incoming calls one at a time.  So it may need to reset as each call ends by the caller.

Comment: When you say "google phone" do you mean ["Google Voice"](https://www.google.com/voice)?

Comment: Yes, I am using "Google Voice" to call my PC.  When I receive a call a dialog box appears with 3 buttons "Answer", "Screen", and "Ignore" I am wanting the "Answer" button auto click whenever a call is received.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WinWait` command with `WinText` parameter, as [said here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic49183.html)